# xcode generates an internal error message

Tags: xcode

When I'm trying to open my project, I get an "Internal error" message. Do you have any idea about what is happening?

> Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

and details are looking like this:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-943/Framework/Classes/Model/Execution/RunContext/IDEBuildSchemeAction.m:912
Details:  (_buildableReference) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDEBuildActionEntry: 0x403120140>
Method:   -dvt_awakeFromXMLUnarchiver:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010b6a8366 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010ad201a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010b246e89 -[IDEBuildActionEntry dvt_awakeFromXMLUnarchiver:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x000000010ad2585a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010ace024a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x000000010ad25551 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010ace024a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010ad25551 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x000000010ace024a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x000000010ad25551 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x000000010ace024a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 11  0x000000010acdff6a -[DVTXMLUnarchiver _readAndReturnError:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12  0x000000010acdfc84 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeWithRootObject:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 13  0x000000010b245cc5 +[IDEScheme schemeFromXMLData:withRunContextManager:customDataStoreContainer:customDataSpecifier:isShown:orderHint:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 14  0x000000010b24542e -[IDERunContextManager _updateMap:contextForCustomDataStore:specifier:] (in IDEFoundation)
 15  0x000000010b244b6f -[IDERunContextManager _customDataStoresDidUpdate] (in IDEFoundation)
 16  0x000000010ad2a9d0 -[NSObject(DVTPropertyLinking) dvt_addObserverWithName:toKeyPath:ofObject:block:] (in DVTFoundation)
 17  0x000000010b244554 -[IDERunContextManager initWithWorkspace:] (in IDEFoundation)
 18  0x000000010b2441e5 -[IDEWorkspace _setupRunContextManager] (in IDEFoundation)
 19  0x000000010b29e02e __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
 20  0x00007fff8d9a3b05 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 21  0x00007fff8d96a6d8 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
 22  0x00007fff8d97d936 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)
 23  0x00007fff81bde8ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 24  0x00007fff81be072a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 25  0x00007fff81f3506c __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff81f34676 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x00007fff87a8231f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 28  0x00007fff87a895c9 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 29  0x00007fff87a89456 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 30  0x00007fff86c93f5d _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff86c93861 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff86c9019d -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 33  0x00007fff86f0eb88 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 34  0x000000010acb3eec (in Xcode)
 35  0x0000000000000002
```

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't ever see an "internal error" in a product like Xcode; you're seeing either a bug or a situation that nobody thought would happen. The root cause is probably some sort of malformed project file: we can see from the stack trace that Xcode is reading an XML file, and you said that it happens when Xcode opens your project.

I'd start by creating a new project file and then adding all the files in your project. This can be a pain in the neck, but it's often the most effective way to recover from problems related to the project file.

If that sounds like too much work and you think you know what the problem is, you can try editing your existing project file by hand. Control-click on the project file and pick "Show Package Contents" from the contextual menu to reveal the files inside the project file, which is really a bundle of files. Then open the "project.pbxproj" file in your favorite text editor to see the XML that defines the project. It's not hard to see the structure of the file, so you might be able to spot a problem.

For example, last night I accidentally added Xcode itself as one of my project's frameworks. This caused Xcode to hang, and I had to force quit. To make matters worse, Xcode tries to open the projects that were open when you last quit, so launching Xcode again resulted in another hang. (You can avoid this by holding down the Shift key when you launch Xcode.) I opened the project file with TextMate, found the references to Xcode.app in the linked frameworks section, and deleted them. The surgery was a success and the patient made a full recovery.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a case where either your project file or an Xcode config file has been corrupted.  These are both XML files, which would explain why your stack trace indicates xml parsing issues.  The stack trace also indicates (from the IDE prefixes) that the error occurs while Xcode is attempting to organize itself as an Integrated Development Environment.

Here are a few options:

1. Try to open or create another project in Xcode.  If you are able to do this, then try again to open your existing project in Xcode.
2. Try to open your project in another install of Xcode, either on another machine or another version of Xcode on your current machine.  If the project opens in another install, then reinstall your Xcode.
3. Create a new project.  Copy all your h, m, and resource files in a few at a time.  Set up the project anew.
4. You could always attempt to find some malformed xml by opening the project file in a text editor. (not much fun)